# Reload only specific layoutunit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am using JSF+Spring Webflow and hibernate with Primfaces.
       now i have a layout in which 3 layoutunit defined ( `north` , west , center). whenever i call a page it reloads the whole page instead of center layoutunit.

```
        <!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:beas="http://beas.com/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">



<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <ui:define name="headerIncludes">


    </ui:define>
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootStrapStyle.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/configuration_Agent.css" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/emaven_aggregator.css" />

        <!-- Responsive CSS Link Ends -->

        <style>
body {
    background: #ffffff url("../resources/images/loading.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>


        <ui:insert name="headerIncludes" />
    </h:head>




    <h:body style="color: #616161;margin: 0;padding: 0;"
        styleClass="dashboard-body">
        <p:layout fullPage="true">
            <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="border-radius: 0;"
                id="mainLayout">
                <p:layout closeTitle="Close" collapseTitle="Collapse"
                    expandTitle="Expand">


                    <!-- LEFT MENU Content Ends -->

                    <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false" size="50"
                        minSize="20" maxSize="100"
                        styleClass="left_menu_area ui-widget-header">



                        <ui:repeat var="menu" value="#{menuScreenTransformer.parentMenu}">
                            <h:form id="menus">
                                <!-- #{!managePatientTO.clinicBoolean?'switcher_clinical':'switcher_nonclinical'}  -->
                                <p:commandButton id="home"
                                    styleClass="hvr-overline-from-left #{menu.menuImage} ui-state-default"
                                    icon="" title="#{menu.menuDesc}"
                                    actionListener="#{flowManager.performPageAction(menu.childflag?(menu.screenName):'null')}" />
                                <p:tooltip id="toolTipFocus" for="home" value="#{menu.menuDesc}" />
                                <p:menu overlay="true" trigger="home" triggerEvent="mousedown"
                                    rendered="#{!menu.childflag}" my="right top" at="left top"
                                    toggleable="false" styleClass="mapping_menue"
                                    style="width:300px; !important;"
                                    model="#{menuScreenTransformer.fetchMenuModel(menu.menuID)}" />
                            </h:form>
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <!-- <ui:repeat var="submenu" value="#{menu.list}" >



        <!-- <p:separator styleClass="footer_separator" style="width:95% !important;"></p:separator> -->
                        <!-- </div> -->
                    </p:layoutUnit>

                    <!-- LEFT MENU Content Ends -->

                    <p:layoutUnit position="north" maxSize="80" minSize="50"
                        visible="true" header="abc" rendered="true"
                        style=" overflow: hidden;" styleClass="borderHeaderLine">
                        <!--lock screen  -->
                        <h:form id="dialogInputForm">



                        </h:form>

                        <h:form id="menuForm">
                            <p:outputPanel id="page" autoUpdate="true" layout="block">
                                <!-- <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%"
                                    columnClasses="headerCol1Style,headerCol2Style,headerCol3Style"> -->
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row-fluid header-row">
                                        <div class="span12">

                                            <div class="span3">
                                                <p:outputPanel layout="block">
                                                    <p:graphicImage
                                                        value="#{pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/edios.png"
                                                        rendered="#{loginApp.applicationLogo != 'L2'}"
                                                        style="max-height:52px;" />

                                                    <p:graphicImage
                                                        value="#{pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/velos_logo.png"
                                                        rendered="#{loginApp.applicationLogo == 'L2'}"
                                                        style="max-height:52px;" />
                                                    <p:spacer
                                                        rendered="#{applicationManager.appParameter.appLogoPath == ''}" />
                                                </p:outputPanel>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="span6">

                                                <h:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%"
                                                    styleClass="header-heading-class">
                                                    <p:outputPanel layout="block"
                                                        styleClass="tag-line  header-heading-class">
                                                        <h:outputText
                                                            value="#{appLoginParameter['BayaTreeAppHeader']}"
                                                            rendered="#{loginApp.applicationLogo != 'L2'}" />
                                                        <h:outputText
                                                            value="#{appLoginParameter['VelosAppHeader']}"
                                                            rendered="#{loginApp.applicationLogo == 'L2'}" />

                                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                                    <p:outputPanel layout="block"
                                                        styleClass="login-body version-div"
                                                        style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{appLoginParameter['Version']}"></h:outputText>
                                                        <h:outputText value="#{loginApp.serviceEnvironment}" />
                                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                                </h:panelGrid>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="span3">




                                                <div class="right_menu top_right_menu">


                                                    <!-- <a class="tooltips2"  > -->
                                                    <p:button id="UserInfo" icon="fa fa-user fa-lg"
                                                        styleClass="users_setting" />


                                                    <!-- </a> -->


                                                    <p:commandButton id="accsetting" icon="fa fa-cog fa-lg"
                                                        styleClass="settings"
                                                        actionListener="#{flowManager.performPageAction('ACCOUNT_SETTINGS')}"
                                                        onclick=" PF('dlg').show();" />
                                                    <p:tooltip id="toolTipFade1" for="accsetting"
                                                        value="#{appLabel['accountSettings']}" />


                                                    <p:commandButton id="logout" icon="fa fa-power-off fa-lg"
                                                        styleClass="user_logout" action="signOut"
                                                        actionListener="#{manageLayout.checkFlagForLogout}"
                                                        onclick=" PF('dlg').show();" />
                                                    <p:tooltip id="toolTipFade2" for="logout"
                                                        value="#{appLabel['logOut']}" />


                                                </div>

                                                <!-- Right Menu Ends  -->

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </h:form>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                        <div class="unsupported_res">ediosPRS Web Application does
                            not support this Resolution.</div>
                        <h:form id="menu">

                            <p:commandButton id="sessionTimeOut" action="autoLogout"
                                actionListener="#{manageLayout.checkFlagForLogout}"
                                onclick=" PF('dlg').show();" style="display:none;" />
                            <!-- <p:menubar model="#{menuScreenTransformer.menuModel}" widgetVar="menu"
                                styleClass="menuhome  " autoDisplay="false" /> -->
                            <!-- ui-widget-content ui-state-default -->
                        </h:form>
                        <h:form id="form">
                            <p:outputPanel layout="block" id="centerPanel">
                                <p:growl id="globalGrowl" autoUpdate="true"
                                    widgetVar="globalGrowl" life="#{appLabel['MsgAutoCloseTime']}" />
                                <ui:insert name="content" />
                                <p:idleMonitor
                                    timeout="#{sessionManager.userLoginDetailTO.sessionTimeoutMin*60000-appLabel['startTimerSessionTimeout']*1000}">
                                    <p:ajax event="idle" onstart="PF('idleDialog').show();" />
                                </p:idleMonitor>

                                <p:dialog header="#{appLabel['sessionExpire']}"
                                    widgetVar="idleDialog" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
                                    modal="true" width="580" height="100" closable="false"
                                    draggable="false" resizable="false"
                                    onShow="startTimer(#{appLabel['startTimerSessionTimeout']})"
                                    appendTo="@(body)">

                                    <div class="text_container_box">

                                        <div class="message_of_use1">

                                            <div class="message_display_div_time_out">




                                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left;"></span>
                                                <span> #{appMessage['loggedOffTimeMessage']} <span
                                                    id="dialog-countdown" style="font-weight: bold"></span>
                                                    #{appMessage['secondsMessage']}
                                                </span> <span> #{appMessage['continueSessionMessage']} </span> <span
                                                    class="timed_out_buttons"> <p:commandButton
                                                        value="#{appLabel['keepWorking']}"
                                                        onclick="clearTimeInterval()" /> <p:spacer width="8"></p:spacer>
                                                    <p:commandButton value="#{appLabel['logOutSession']}"
                                                        onclick="logOff()" />
                                                </span>
                                            </div>


                                        </div>

                                    </div>



                                </p:dialog>



                                <p:overlayPanel id="overLayId" for="menuForm:UserInfo"
                                    showEffect="fold" hideEffect="fold" showEvent="mouseover"
                                    hideEvent="mouseleave" dismissable="true"
                                    styleClass="overlaypanel" style="width:220px; height:150px;">

                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{appLabel['L_User_Name']}"
                                        style="font-weight: bold;"></p:outputLabel>

                                    <p:outputLabel
                                        value="#{sessionManager.userLoginDetailTO.firstName}  #{sessionManager.userLoginDetailTO.lastName} "
                                        style="width:100%; padding-left:10px;"></p:outputLabel>

                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{appLabel['Login_Name_Group_Name']}"
                                        style="font-weight: bold; margin-top:10px;"></p:outputLabel>

                                    <p:outputLabel
                                        value="#{sessionManager.userName} (#{sessionManager.userLoginDetailTO.defaultGroupName}) "
                                        style="width:100%;  padding-left:10px;"></p:outputLabel>

                                    <!--  <p:outputLabel value=""></p:outputLabel> -->
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{appLabel['lastLoggedInDateAndTime']}"
                                        style=" font-weight: bold;width:100%; margin-top:10px;">
                                        <f:convertDateTime
                                            pattern="#{sessionManager.defaultDateFormat}  #{sessionManager.defaultTimeFormat}" />
                                    </p:outputLabel>

                                    <p:outputLabel id="lastLogedDateID"
                                        value="#{securityManager.getLastLoggedInTimeOfUser()}"
                                        style="width:100%; padding-left:10px;">

                                        <f:convertDateTime
                                            pattern="#{sessionManager.defaultDateFormat}"
                                            for="lastLogedDateID" style="width:100%;" />
                                    </p:outputLabel>
                                </p:overlayPanel>





                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </h:form>
                    </p:layoutUnit>
                </p:layout>
            </p:layoutUnit>
            <beas:progress progressId="dlgForMenuClick" />
        </p:layout>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>


`using this properties in POM.xml
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springsecurity-version>3.0.2.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
    <spring-webflow-version>2.3.2.RELEASE</spring-webflow-version>
    <jsf-version>2.1.3</jsf-version>
    <primefaces-version>5.2</primefaces-version>
    <theme.version>1.0.10</theme.version>
</properties>`
```

Comment: @BalusC Is that possible to achieve the same in spring-webflow framework?

Comment: SWF is not designed for SPA in first place.